# Problems to convert FORTRAN 77-File into FORTRAN 90 in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, fortran90, fortran77

Sorry to ask this question, but I am totally new to Visual Studio and to Fortran .

I have a FORTRAN ( 77?) File Filename.f which I want to edit in Visual studio.

Is there a possibility to edit **only** this file and compile it later in Visual Studio without having to create a whole project? I didn`t find a way to do that.

So I tried to create a new f90-project X in Visual Studio and to copy/paste the code of my Filename.f into that X.f90. I know that I would have to take care of the file-name ( .f -> .f90) and the commentaries ( C -> ! )  but there seem to be problems right at the top of my file.

```
DIMENSION UZ(N,M),VZ(N,M),EZ(N,M)
DIMENSION UP(N,M),VP(N,M),EP(N,M)
1,UPZ(N,M),VPZ(N,M),EPZ(N,M)
DIMENSION RHO(N,M),RHOZ(N,M)
```

The compiler likes thew lines with **DIMENSION**.... but in line 3 he doesn`t like the **1**.

Does anybody know why? What does the **1** mean anyway ?

Comment: Spend a few minutes looking around here on SO for questions, and answers, on the topic of Fortran's *fixed-form source* and *free-form source*.  More particularly, on the *continuation* characters, which ones are usable and where they are to be placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the `1` was in the 6th position of that line.

In **F77** fixed form format, this means that this line is a continuation of the previous line.

Properly converted, this would look like this:

```
DIMENSION UZ(N,M),VZ(N,M),EZ(N,M)
DIMENSION UP(N,M),VP(N,M),EP(N,M)  &
          ,UPZ(N,M),VPZ(N,M),EPZ(N,M)
DIMENSION RHO(N,M),RHOZ(N,M)
```

Comment: I think you're right about the 1 originally being in the 6th position in the line.